# Calculating Items depending on each other

Tags: java, database-design, jpa

I want to develop a java application where a user should be able to add calculation items depending on each other. Consider this scenario:

- Add an item (A) with a value lets say 50
- Add another item (B) which is item A*5
- Add item (C) which has a value of (A*50%)+B
- Delete item (A) fails as long it is used in other items.

I can store the equations as varchar in the database and parse it back in java when I recall using equation parser or something similar. But when I tried this, the problem was what If item A is deleted? The database wont know if the item is linked to another item if I use a varchar. I want the items to be linked to each other using foreign keys, how can I achieve that?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I could not find a proper answer that solves my problems.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Don't tell what you want to do, ask a real question that can be answered.

Comment: sorry my bad, somehow the last part of the question was not posted. I have edited my question

Comment: @aviad Please see the edited question, you don't have to downvote, the last part of the question was not posted, now I have.

Comment: Post the existing database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tree java structure](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/ExpressionTree/index.html) to represent the expression. each node will represent an operator and 2 operands. The concrete values will be at the leaf level. 
The calculation would be a simple in order walk on the tree.

In the DB you will need a representation of the expression (tree) pointing to all its components (tree nodes).

(Or use alternative expression tree DB representation)

```
           EXP1:
        OPERATOR:+
          /    \
         /      \
        /        \
   OPERAND:1   OPERAND:2
```

the DB

**expression entries table**:

```
| ID     | NAME    |  DEPENDS_ON_NODE_ID  |
| 1      | EXP1    |  1                   |
| 2      | EXP1    |  2                   |
| 2      | EXP1    |  3                   |
```

**nodes table**:

```
| ID     | NAME     |  TYPE         |  VALUE |
| 1      | NODE1    |  OPERATOR     |   +    |
| 2      | NODE1    |  OPERAND      |   1    |
| 3      | NODE1    |  OPERAND      |   2    |
```

Comment: I see, I need to think of this way now. A simple question with a nice answer. I dont know why I'm still getting downvotes.